# move file based on the less than max system modified date available

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to move based on the less than max system modified date available

```
Name   date Modified 
file1  14/05/2018 11:21 AM
file2  14/05/2018 11:41 AM
```

In this case we want to move file1 so apart from max system modified date. All remaining files have to move

I have tried below command:

```
move /-y "C:\app\folder1*.txt" "C:\app\folder2\"
```

pause

other step tried

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\app\folder1\" 
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending 
Move-Destination t-Object -Skip 1 
Move-Item -Destination "C:\app\folder2\" |
```

i tried again getting error....| C:\app\folder1>Move-Item -Destination "C:\app\folder2\"

> 'Move-Item' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

thanks

Comment: I honestly don't get what you're trying to achieve. Could you please try to explain in a clearer way? Anyway, I added tag [tag:powershell] as it applies for your 2nd attempt...

Comment: It wasn't really a second attempt, @aschipfl, and they never asked for a powershell based solution. They asked the same [batch-file] question earlier and was given that as an answer. They subsequently deleted the question and aked the same one again, this time including the powershell response they'd previously received to their question. I have therefore removed the powershell tag again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you were aware, but the  other step you tried was `powershell.exe` code not `cmd.exe`.

Something similar to this may do what you require:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "dirSrc=C:\App\Folder1"
Set "dirDst=C:\App\Folder2"
Set "extSrc=*.txt"
If Exist "%dirSrc%\%extSrc%" (CD /D "%dirSrc%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
) Else Exit /B
If Not Exist "%dirDst%\" (MD "%dirDst%" 2>Nul || Exit /B)
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D-H-L-S/O-D/TW "%extSrc%"'
) Do Move /Y "%%A" "%dirDst%">Nul 2>&1
```

*Before you run it, you'll need to make sure that the directories specified in lines `2` and `3` are correct and also the file mask in line `4` is correct.*