# Adding files to archive in Windows script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I wanted to move the files to `archive` folder except the max time stamp in system date modified available in the file and wanted to do it for four different folder like `folder 3` will go to `folder4` and `folder 5` to `folder 6` i.e.`folder`: `file1` has system date modified `12:00 AM` and `file 2` has `12:21 AM` then `file 1` will archive in this way it has to archive all remaining file which is less than latest date modified.

I want this in windows cmd prompt

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\app\folder1\" 
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending 
Move-Destination t-Object -Skip 1 
Move-Item -Destination "C:\app\folder2\" |

**Edit**

I was hoping for a modification of the accepted answer provided in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50326733).

The idea is to run the script in each of the directories instead of just the one `Set` on line `2`

This was the code:

```
@Echo Off
Set "dirSrc=C:\App\Folder1"
Set "dirDst=C:\App\Folder2"
Set "extSrc=*.txt"
If Exist "%dirSrc%\%extSrc%" (CD /D "%dirSrc%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
) Else Exit /B
If Not Exist "%dirDst%\" (MD "%dirDst%" 2>Nul || Exit /B)
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D-H-L-S/O-D/TW "%extSrc%"'
) Do Move /Y "%%A" "%dirDst%">Nul 2>&1
```

The directory tree I was hoping to work with looks similar to this:

```
C:\USERS\GARANG\DOCUMENTS\INPUT_FILES 
|   movefiles.cmd 
| 
+---Advisory_rate 
|   |   Local Project Tracker_2016 - 26 April 2018.xlsx 
|   | 
|   \---Archive 
|           Advise rate mapping - Copy.xls 
|           Advise rate mapping.xls 
|           CbCR Notification Tracker - Copy.xlsx 
|           CbCR Notification Tracker.xlsx 
| 
+---Internation_Project_Tracker1 
|   |   International Project Tracker_2016 - 28 March 2018 - Copy.xlsx 
|   |   International Project Tracker_2016 - 6 March 2018.xlsx 
|   |   Local Project Tracker_2016 - 26 April 2018.xlsx 
|   | 
|   \---Archive 
|           CbCR Notification Tracker - Copy.xlsx 
|           CbCR Notification Tracker.xlsx 
| 
+---Local_Project_Tracker 
|   |   Local Project Tracker_2016 - 26 April 2018 - Copy.xlsx 
|   |   Local Project Tracker_2016 - 26 April 2018.xlsx 
|   | 
|   \---Archive 
|           CbCR Notification Tracker - Copy.xlsx 
|           CbCR Notification Tracker.xlsx 
| 
\---Notification_Tracker 
    |   Local Project Tracker_2016 - 26 April 2018.xlsx 
    | 
    \---Archive 
           CbCR Notification Tracker - Copy.xlsx 
           CbCR Notification Tracker.xlsx
```

Comment: any suggestions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given several exchanges after you accepted my answer in your last question, I have updated your question to include the latest confirmed requirements and a modification of my last answer below:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "dirSrc=C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files"
Set "dirDst=Archive"
Set "extSrc=*.xls"
CD /D "%dirSrc%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For /D %%A In (*) Do (PushD "%%A"
    For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%B In (
        'Dir /B/A-D-H-L-S/O-D/TW "%extSrc%" 2^>Nul') Do (
        If Not Exist "%dirDst%\" MD "%dirDst%"
        Move /Y "%%B" "%dirDst%">Nul 2>&1)
    PopD)
```

Place this script, **`movefiles.cmd`**, into the source directory, *(as `Set` on line `2`)*, **`C:\Users\garang\Documents\input_files`** and double-click it.

*This script doesn't assume that the Archive directories already exist, if they do not, they will be created.*

Comment: when i copy and paste files from one folder to another is not transferrring

Comment: @ShreeS, the script works for me and I cannot afford to spend any more time on this. You are aware that this script doesn't run perpetually aren't you? _(every time you want it to run you have to double click it again!)_ I've no other suggestion or modification, please allow other respondees to help you with your question.

Comment: can you give ur email id or you can join go to meeting session..all things will be cleared

Comment: it is just doing same day files and not for same month and year